# Google Cloud Run job succeeding in 2 seconds without included script running

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have Google Cloud Run job that contains a script I need ran. The script is loading data into Google Bigquery. I have a Dockerfile that defines all pre-requisites I need (loading a custom python library from a github Repo, installing python libraries, etc).

When I build the container the script runs as expected and I see results in BQ.

But when I run the job in Cloud Run it doesn't run as expected.

I tried manually running the job as well as scheduling a Cloud Scheduler Cron job.

I expected it the script to execute and then see data in BQ.

However I notice that the job is running in 2 seconds or so and succeeding and BQ shows no changes after the run. Also, the logs only tell me that the container exited with status 0 and gives no information, including stdout dumps.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE: ISSUE RESOLVED**

However my answer may not be the best practice and I may still be missing something here. Will be happy to accept any answers helping me and the greater Stack Overflow community understand more here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more? Your script argument, your container Dockerfile, your Cloud Run job configuration,...

Comment: @nerdydude777 please post your solution as an answer, to follow Stackoverflow best practices.

Comment: Please post an answer instead of including the solution in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my lack of understanding of what the docker runtime (engine? IDK the right word here) does with built containers.

I thought that a Docker image would run through all the commands listed in the Dockerfile every time.

Thus (Assuming an Ubuntu base image for this example),

```
...
All awesome image set up stuff here
...

RUN python3 my_awesome_script.py
```

Would mean that every time the container was ran it would end up running `my_awesome_script.py`.

**I WAS WRONG**

Turns out `docker container run my_awesome_image` (in local) will run the image as it was *after all the steps in the Dockerfile are completed*.

Therefore a Dockerfile with no Flask app or other service running will simply exit.

This is what I noticed locally and in GCP as well. The job would simply finish in 20 seconds with a 'success'.

Running `docker container run -ti my_awesome_image` will get me to a TTY in the image itself and then I can issue `python3 my_awesome_script.py` for the results I want.

After some trial and error in the Google Cloud Run Jobs interface I found the "Container Arguments" section and was able issue `python3 my_awesome_script.py`.

This resolved my issue.